# Does the Windows registry hold details of the processor's capabilities?

Tags: windows, cpu, windows-registry, x86

I have a strange situation which I hope someone can shed light on.  I have an old HP laptop NC6320 with a triple boot running Windows XP, 7 and Linux Mint. It's an Intel Core 2 T5600 which supports PAE, NX and SSE2.  And the laptop is brilliant because it has every port imaginable!

Anyway I ran the Windows 8.1 upgrade assistant on my Windows 7 to see if it were possible and it said all was fine except for a couple of old bits of software.  So I therefore made a new partition (quadruple boot) and loaded a second copy of Windows 7 on it ready to upgrade to 8.1 and ran the assistant again and it said "You can't install Windows 8.1 because your processor doesn't support NX."  It does.  Intel say so, Everest says so, and the other Windows 7 partition said so.

So my question is why would that happen? Does Windows store the machine configuration in the registry somewhere and has got it wrong on my second install?  It seems most strange.  Any info - or even theories - most welcome.

Comment: aida32 should report relevant information. CPU capabilities can also be queried via ASM CPUID opcode. NX is bit 20.

Comment: PAE, NX and SSE2 are all supported by the processor ssnobody. And my question Ramhound is why would Windows 7 on one partition say NX is supported, while Windows 7 on another partition on the same machine and installed with the same DVD says NX isn't supported?  If you say Windows doesn't hold info in the registry then why on earth would/could that happen?

Comment: My guess, you don't have the chipset driver properly installed.

Comment: the  Intel Core 2 T5600 does support it. It is called Execute-Disable-Bit for Intel CPUs.

Comment: That was an excellent idea krowe - I thought you'd cracked it!  Re-installed latest chipset drivers and ...... result still the same.  Shame, and baffling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I have a result but only a theory on how it came to be.  Having tried all options I could think of - including krowe's sensible suggestion - and got nowhere I started again from scratch.

So fresh partition, fresh install, and this time the Windows update assistant doesn't say "doesn't support NX".  So I think Ramhound you must be wrong.  I believe during installation Windows interrogates all the hardware and probably stores the results in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor and once there they are set in stone whether right or wrong.

As for Ramhound's "You have not shared enough information for me to conclude the actual reason your getting told this."  Here is the answer.

The reason is that I intend to leave my new second copy of Windows 7 to update itself to Windows 10.  On a multiboot system with a MBR and BIOS and also GRUB in its own partition for Linux, I think attempting to install Windows 10 to a new partition from an iso might cause havoc as it'll want to use UEFI I'm sure and probably won't offer alternative options.  But updating an existing installation already written into the MBR may possibly get round that.  And the reason I've referred to "Windows update assistant for 8.1" is because there isn't one for Windows 10 but the requirements will probably be about the same.

If anyone wants to know the result after it happens leave a comment!  An adventure into the unknown (although I have a cloned disc made before I started playing just in case).